# How to configure IntelliJ to consider text files when renaming classes

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, refactoring, file-rename

I'm having a gradle project with the following structure:

```
src
    docs/asciidoc contains asciidoctor documents
    main/java contains java source code (surprise)
    test/java contains java source for tests
```

The AsciiDoctor documents reference classes in the src folders. When I rename classes in the source folders with IntelliJ Idea, I kind of expected it to propose changing the occurences of that name in the AsciiDoctor files as well, but it doesn't although I have the "Search in comments and Strings" checkbox checked.

Can I enable the desired behavior by some configuration?

Answer (score 1):

At first I suspected it had something to do with the maven structure (/src/docs is not exactly standard but as far as I know there isn't an official suggestion anyway), but I remember about a second checkbox in the same interface (press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> twice) `Search for text occurrences`, and with that enabled it seems to work as expected, at least on IJ 14. Below a sample with both the scenarios and also with file under /src/resources & /src/docs

[image: Search for text occurrences]

Comment: the checkbox is checked, still doesn't work. My version is 16.2 ... wondering if I found a bug.

Comment: @JensSchauder At times the "Find" window just pops-up for a short time, just as in the attached GIF and I kind of miss it. If you manually open it, and nothing is there, then perhaps it is indeed a bug. You could check [their tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) to see if there's anything in there. Unfortunately I can't do this now because I'm in a meeting

Comment: I just tried it with a trivial project and it works just fine. Just not in the real one ...Even restarted with invalidating the caches. Didn't help.

Comment: @JensSchauder What if you close the project, move the `.iml` file & `.idea` folder from the root to some other place outside, and re-import the project? And if it works, maybe run a directory diff on the before mentioned files just to figure it out... Or just run a diff with the trivial project's config (but this may be trickier)...